# VBA Find string in Strings array

Tags: arrays, vba, string

I am trying to dimension a string and look if it is contained in an array but I get "ByRef argument type mismatch"

My code:

```
Dim SC140_UpperFilmTypeArray
SC140_UpperFilmTypeArray = Array("Flexible")

Dim UpperFilmType As String
UpperFilmType = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Machine Specification").Cells(Cells.Find("Upper Film Type", lookat:=xlWhole).Row, ActiveCell.Column).Value

If IsInArray(SC140_UpperFilmTypeArray, UpperFilmType) Then
MsgBox ("Great success!")
End If
```

The function goes as follows:

```
Function IsInArray(arr As Variant, myVal As Integer) As Boolean

   Dim mtch
   mtch = Application.Match(myVal, arr, True)
   If Not IsError(mtch) Then
     If mtch = UBound(arr) Then
        If arr(UBound(arr)) = myVal Then IsInArray = True: Exit Function
     Else
        IsInArray = True: Exit Function
     End If
   End If
   IsInArray = False
End Function
```

What is the mistake here?

Comment: You are mixing datatypes: `IsInArray` expects a variant and an **Integer** - but you supply a variant and a **string** < `Dim UpperFilmType As String`

Comment: Alright, well how do I fix that? Initially that code was written to deal with integer lists. So I think your reasoning is spot on! I need it working, both, with integers and strings

Comment: Then you have to write `myVal as Variant` within the parameter declaration of `IsInArray`

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks, friend! That was the mistake I guess